# What has happened to 'tick' in ANS Forth?

Tags: forth, gforth

As I remembered 'tick' from FIG-Forth, it could be used without abortion when a word wasn't in the wordlist:

```
' the_word
```

gave a reference to the word if it was in the word-list and gave 'false' otherwise.

Is it possible to construct something like that in ANS Forth to be used with [if], [then] and [else]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
: tick ( a u -- xt|f ) bl word find 0= if drop 0 then ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The FIG-Forth document says:

> Leaves the parameter field address of dictionary word *nnnn*.  As a
>   compiler directive, executes in a colon-definition to compile the
>   address as a literal.  If the word is not found after a search of
>   CONTEXT and CURRENT, an appropriate error message is given.

Although it is entirely possible the version of FIG-Forth you where using did not abide by the standard, and returned false.